# Get Unique value "Hashcode" from a Set

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

i wanna represent a set of two int values as one value, so i can have:

`x = f(a,b) = f(b,a)`

so x should not represent more than one set.

Any help please.

Comment: which one should hold x?

Comment: x should hold a value that represent the set , for eg i can use the sum but there is a lot of sets having the same sum

Comment: Why don't you use a `frozenset`? They are hashable.

Comment: `x = id(a) + id(b)`? I think this should work. `id(a)` generates unique identifier for an object.

Comment: Maybe it will help set([1, 2]) == set([2, 1]) -> True.

Comment: @RohitJain but the sum of two id unique values may not be unique

Comment: @alexvassel yeah that's the standard way , but i have some constraints so i should make comparaison using just one value representing the set

Comment: @DanD. i searched for a function in frozenset which could give a hashcode but i have not found it

Comment: Try `hash(frozenset([a, b]))`.

Comment: From the description of your requirements what you're looking for is most definitely *not* a hash function. I'd recommend getting the terminology straight to avoid further confusion.

Comment: thanks a lot @Blckknght can you move you comment into answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `frozenset` type is hashable, and you can create one from any iterable. To get the hash value, just use the built-in `hash` function:

```
x = hash(frozenset([a, b]))
```

Comment: I didn't vote either way, but this clearly fails the "x should not represent more than one set" requirement.

Comment: i think that hash() could return a unique value for any set, @NPE can you explain why that could fail ?

Comment: @geogeek: There's no guarantee that different sets won't hash down to the same value, and you're asking for such a guarantee (unless I am misreading your question).

Comment: @NPE what would be the solution to guarantee that different sets won't hash down to the same value ?

Comment: @NPE's correct that there's no guarantee that there won't be hash collisions between different sets. This is a fundamental limitation of hash functions: they lose data. Python's `hash` returns a 32 bit integer, so there's a maximum of 2**32 different hash values for 2**63 two-int sets. In theory it should be very hard to find two sets that have the same hash, but I'm not sure if Python's implementation tries to be particularly secure against a dedicated "attack". If your use case is limited to storing a single int value though, you're probably not going to find much else that's better.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an integer as value for x, I think returning the ordered tuple should be ok (it works for all number of values):

```
>>> s = {1, 2}
>>> s2 = {2, 1}
>>> f = lambda s: tuple(sorted(s))
>>> f(s)
(1, 2)
>>> f(s2)
(1, 2)
>>> f(s) == f(s2)
True
```